# How is shift operator implemented?

Tags: bit-shift

I want to know when I do 4<<2, what exactly happens underneath?? are there any multiplications performed or how is the value computed. if you have a reference to the implementation of shift operators please reply me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally this is a processor instruction (directly done on the processor).

It simply does shift the bits in memory:

```
int a = 3; // a = 0 0 1 1
a << 1;    // a = 0 1 1 0 = 6
a << 1;    // a = 1 1 0 0 = 12
```

If you are looking for insight on how processors work in a very low level, [Code](http://www.charlespetzold.com/code/) by Charles Petzold is a fantastic book to read.

Comment: AFAK: most shifts are actually done in the CPU registers, then stored to memory as needed.

Answer (score 3):

In your particular case the compiler will shortcut it to the constant, but in general instruction set of processors includes special opcodes (operation codes, commands) to perform bit shift operations.

[Here's good explanation](http://webster.cs.ucr.edu/AoA/Windows/HTML/DataRepresentationa6.html) of how this works.

Answer (score 1):

In hardware terms, each output bit is generated by selecting one of the input bits.  No multipliers required, just a lot of multiplexing.

Answer (score 1):

It's worthwhile to note that some processors have instructions that can bit shift any amount in a fixed amount of time, some have instructions which can shift a variable amount but will take a variable amount of time to do it (so shifting something left 31 bits may take awhile), and others are limited to instructions which shift one bit at a time.  While one generally shouldn't worry about such fussy implementation details, there can be some huge performance differences between various ways of achieving common results.

For example, using (1<

```
  if (shift_amount & 16)
    longvar >>= 16;
  if (shift_amount & 8)
    longvar >>= 8;
  if (shift_amount & 4)
    longvar >>= 4; /* If processor has optimization for this */
  longvar >>= (shift_amount & 3);
```

Totally counter-productive if an instruction exists for fast shifting, but a potentially huge speedup (6x or better) on some 8-bit machines.

Answer (score 0):

All processors probably have shift instructions, [here](http://www.osdata.com/topic/language/asm/shiftrot.htm) are some examples of their assembly language counterparts.